# Sitecore - ControllerRendering complaining about Controller "not found or does not implement IController."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore

So I have created my Controller Rendering, that uses controller

```
Sitecore.Social.Twitter.Client.Mvc.Areas.Social.Controllers.TwitterConnectorController
```

like so:

[image]

But when I try to access the page, I get an error complaining about the Controller not being controller enough:

[image]

But if I inspect the dll with the Object Viewer, the controller in question indeed inherits from IController:

[image]

So, what is going on here? Why am I receiving this error?

EDIT: I suspect that perhaps the error message is merely a symptom, and Sitecore is somehow unable to access the controller in the DLL. What factors could cause this behavior, and how can I debug them?

Comment: Make sure that you don't use some custom inversion of control container which requires your controllers to be registered.

Comment: @Emanuele, did you find a resolution for this? I am investigating the same thing.

Comment: Same here appreciate it if someone tackled this let us know. thanks

Answer (score 3):

This link worked for me:
http://jockstothecore.com/adventures-in-dependency-injection/

Basically fully qualified controller names bug out the system. I updated mine to use the class name (minus the "controller" word) and proper action and it solved my issue.

Comment: Finally fixed, wasted half a day on this!

Answer (score 1):

I checked TwitterConnectorController and I don't see any connection between /ajax/sociallogin and TwitterConnectorController

Please search for sociallogin controller and check if is inherits from 
from SitecoreController

Comment: Hi, you don't see it because it's a connection I made myself - I didn't took a screenshot before as that's a part that I am confident about, however here it is: http://i.imgur.com/2i8NRUs.png

Comment: Can you remove other renderings and add just that Twitter controller.

Comment: I tried it - I am now no longer receiving the error, but nothing seems to happen at all. Is there any way I can check whether a method inside a DLL was called?

Answer (score 0):

When I turned current framework of project to

> .NET Framework 4.6.1

previously scaffolding was also not working and it started to work.